# Problema con funciones y bucle for

Tags: javascript, funciones, loops

No consigo hacer de forma efectiva que mientras ejecute la función `readSuccessB(evt,file)`, se pause el bucle y reanude justo después de finalizar dicha función.

He probado con **callbacks** creando variables para que si se está ejecutando no llame la función `readSuccessA`, pero para entonces, el valor `i` ya suma `1` y no se puede ejecutar esa función. Probé restándole `1` a `i`, pero creo un **bucle infinito**.

Mi codigo:

```
function openFiles(evt){

    var files =$(evt)[0].files;

    function anadir_archivo(evt){
      var total_subidas=files.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < total_subidas; i++) {

        var file=files[i];

        reader = new FileReader();

        if(total_subidas==1||i+1==total_subidas){
          reader.onload = readSuccessA(evt,file);
        }else{
          reader.onload = readSuccessB(evt,file);         
        }

        function readSuccessA(evt,file) {
          return function(e){
            $('fieldset.subir_imagen>legend+div+label+div+input[type=file]').appendTo($(evt).prev().prev().prev('div').append('<div title="'+file.name+'"><img src="'+e.target.result+'" alt="No se pudo cargar" /><div>'+file.name+'</div></div>').children()).attr({'id':'','onchange':''});
          }
        }
        function readSuccessB(evt,file) {
          return function(e){
            $(evt).prev().prev().prev('div').append('<div title="'+file.name+'"><img src="'+e.target.result+'" alt="No se pudo cargar" /><div>'+file.name+'</div></div>');
          }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(evt.files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con un bucle `while` añadiendo el +1 en el callback? Y aparte, tienes definiciones de funciones dentro de funciones dentro de bucles... quizás se podría reorganizar el código para que sea más limpio (aunque eso no afectaría al problema en sí).

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] para ver el problema mejor?

Comment: Hola no he probado con while pero si me surge algún problema similar lo intentare tal vez sea otra posible solución. Lo he solucionado de la forma que me explico Asier Villanueva, no se si hay que marcar el post como solucionado o algo. Saludos

Comment: Me alegra leer que la respuesta de Asier te funcionara. Puedes marcarla como aceptada pulsando en el ✔️ en la parte superior izquierda de la respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es llevar el contador del fichero a procesar en una variable externa y llamar en el callback del evento `onLoad` (`readSuccessA` o `readSuccessB`) la función para leer el siguiente fichero.

Algo así:

```
function openFiles(evt){
    var files =$(evt)[0].files;

    function anadir_archivo(evt){
        var total_subidas=files.length;
        var i = 0;

        leerActual();

        function leerActual(){
            // Ya se han procesado todos
            if (i >= files.length) return;

            var file=files[i];

            reader = new FileReader();

            if(total_subidas == 1 || i + 1 == total_subidas){
              reader.onload = readSuccessA(evt,file);
            }else{
              reader.onload = readSuccessB(evt,file);         
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(evt.files[i]);
            // Aumenta el contador
            i++;
        }

        function readSuccessA(evt,file) {
          return function(e){
            $('fieldset.subir_imagen>legend+div+label+div+input[type=file]').appendTo($(evt).prev().prev().prev('div').append('<div title="'+file.name+'"><img src="'+e.target.result+'" alt="No se pudo cargar" /><div>'+file.name+'</div></div>').children()).attr({'id':'','onchange':''});
            // Procesar el siguiente fichero
            leerActual();
          }
        }
        function readSuccessB(evt,file) {
          return function(e){
            $(evt).prev().prev().prev('div').append('<div title="'+file.name+'"><img src="'+e.target.result+'" alt="No se pudo cargar" /><div>'+file.name+'</div></div>');
            // Procesar el siguiente fichero
            leerActual();
          }
        }
    }
}
```